# How to make a Django UpdateView only work the first time?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I two objects with a many-to-one relationship, like a `Car` and a `Manufacturer`, and would like to capture the `first_car_name` of the `Manufacturer`, that is, the first car that the manufacturer created.

I have the following two models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_car_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('manufacturer-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.id})


class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        'Manufacturer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

the following `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from myapp.models import Manufacturer, Car


class ManufacturerDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Manufacturer


class AddCarView(UpdateView):
    model = Manufacturer
    fields = ['first_car_name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        Car.objects.get_or_create(
            name=form.cleaned_data['first_car_name'],
            manufacturer=self.object)

        self.object.refresh_from_db()
        if self.object.car_set.count() == 1:
            return super().form_valid(form)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

the following `urls.py`,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('manufacturer/<int:pk>/', views.ManufacturerDetailView.as_view(), name='manufacturer-detail'),
    path('manufacturer/<int:pk>/add-car/', views.AddCarView.as_view(), name='add-car')
]
```

and the following unit test in `tests.py`:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from myapp.models import Manufacturer, Car


class ManufacturerViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_add_car(self):
        manufacturer = Manufacturer.objects.create(name='Ford')

        self.client.post(
            reverse('add-car', kwargs={'pk': manufacturer.id}),
            data={'first_car_name': 'Model T'})

        self.assertEqual(Car.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(Car.objects.first().name, 'Model T')
        self.assertEqual(Car.objects.first().manufacturer, manufacturer)

        manufacturer.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(manufacturer.first_car_name, 'Model T')

        self.client.post(
            reverse('add-car', kwargs={'pk': manufacturer.id}),
            data={'first_car_name': 'Focus'})

        manufacturer.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(manufacturer.first_car_name, 'Model T')
```

What I notice is that when I comment out the line

```
self.objects.refresh_from_db()
```

in the overridden `form_valid()` method, the test passes, but as it is, I get the following assertion error:

```
> 
python manage.py test myapp.tests
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_add_car (myapp.tests.ManufacturerViewTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/myproject/myapp/tests.py", line 20, in test_add_car
    self.assertEqual(manufacturer.first_car_name, 'Model T')
AssertionError: '' != 'Model T'
+ Model T

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.017s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I'm having a bit of difficulty pinning down why refreshing the model instance from the database is causing this test to fail, and in any case, it seems to be a bit 'fragile' if that is the case. Any ideas how I can fix this error?

(By the way, I have a working implementation which is equivalent to a `CreateView` for the `Car` model which in its `form_valid()` method updates the `Manufacturer`, but for consistency reasons I'd like this to be an `UpdateView` of the `Manufacturer` model).

Comment: Does the template by any change renders the `car_set` of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when you enter the `form_valid()` method, the form data has already been saved to `self.object` but not yet committed to the database, so when you run `self.object.refresh_from_db()` you 'lose' the form data before you do the `self.object = form.save()` in the call to `super().form_valid(form)`. I ended up approaching this differently by making this a model view of the `Carl` model rather than the `Manufacturer` one.